# Why is Linux machine sending ARP request for an IP on a different subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, router, vpn, arp

We have a linux machine, on the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet sending arp requests when we try to connect to a machine on the 192.168.5.0/24 network. (The arp requests are for the machine at 192.168.5.10, not the default gateway) There is a default gateway set, and I can see it in netstat -r. It is supposed to send all remote(not same subnet) traffic to the gateway at 192.168.2.1. I checked the subnet mask, and it is indeed 255.255.255.0. So it should be sending ARP requests to get the mac of the default gateway, not the mac of a remote IP. Any ideas why it's sending arp requests? Not sure if this makes a difference, but there is a site to site VPN between the two subnets.

```
# ip route get 192.168.5.10
192.168.5.10 dev bond0  src 192.168.2.42
       cache  ipid 0x9fe7

# ip route
default via 192.168.2.1 dev bond0
192.168.2.0/24 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.42

# ip rule
   0:      from all lookup local
   32766:  from all lookup main
   32767:  from all lookup default
```

Let me know if you need additional details.

Thank you.

Comment: What does your full routing table (`ip route get 192.168.5.10; ip route; ip rule`) look like?

Comment: Is this a `Layer 2` or a `Layer 3` VPN? If it is a Layer2, then it makes sense that ARP packets from the **other** subnet cross the boundary between the two, while, if it is a Layer 3 VPN, this cannot occur. But then: is `192.168.5.0/24` or something including this net, the other site's LAN?

Comment: @grawity     
 ~ # ip route get 192.168.5.10  
192.168.5.10 dev bond0  src 192.168.2.42  
    cache  ipid 0x9fe7    

~ # ip route  
default via 192.168.2.1 dev bond0  
192.168.2.0/24 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.42  

~ # ip rule  
0:      from all lookup local  
32766:  from all lookup main  
32767:  from all lookup default

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like rather than hopping through the gateway, those packets are taking the more direct route of the VPN.  In the case of a VPN, the two networks are basically one larger one (not very technical terms, but you get the idea).

Is there a reason you need the ARP request to go to the gateway?  If it works, then I wouldn't worry about it.  If you really wanted to test it out, shut down the VPN server and wait for the VPN to drop.  You'll then see packets going through the gateway, I suspect.

Comment: Unfortunately the arp requests are not getting responses - there is currently no traffic between the two machines. What I don't get is how the machine could be aware of the VPN situation. Doesn't it just refer to its routing table and act accordingly? Which in this case would be to send arp request for the gateway IP? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm, well then perhaps the routing table is 'hiding' the gateway, in such a way that it just treats it like an invisible part of the network.  Is the gateway properly configured such that traffic may pass between hosts?